# QML changing (x,y) drag-position of drag-target

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

My goal is to set a new position if `drag.active == true`.

How can i change the (x,y) drag-position of an `drag.target` in qml?

On the drag active , the `drag.target` should take a new position and should be afterwards dragable.

```
states: [
  State {
    when: tab.Drag.active
    ParentChange {
      target: tab
      parent: rootTabbar
    }
    AnchorChanges {
      target: tab;
      anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined;
      anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
   }
   PropertyChanges {
     target: tab;
     x: x + delegateRoot.mouseX - tab.width/2

  }
 }
]
```

This causes a binding-loop and creates high cpu usage

```
qrc:/TabBar/TabBar.qml:368:25: QML RootTab: Binding loop detected for property "x"
```

How can i prevent this binding loop and reposition the `drag.target`

Comment: In declarative property bindings, you can't use the value of a property to calculate the value of the property itself. When the value is evaluated, the property changes, which causes the expression to change, which again changes the property and so on => binding loop.